# Leer un archivo JSON en ESP8266

Tags: json, lua

Necesito ayuda para leer un archivo JSON en una esp8266, la esp debe abrir el archivo mediante un código en LUA, leer los datos que contiene para asignarlos a la configuración de la ip estática.
el archivo json contiene lo siguiente:

```
{
 "ip": "192.168.2.252", 
 "password": "contraseña del router", 
 "ide": "1261527000323", 
 "ssid": "SSID de mi router", 
 "gateway": "ip de mi router"
}
```

El problema es que soy nuevo en LUA así que aun no logro encontrar información que me ayude.

Comment: No se como es "esp8266", pero una sugerencia habria echa una mirada a JSON.NET

Comment: @Eder, ¿Podrías añadir algo del fichero json? Si no es complejo, su transformación a una tabla de lua debería ser trivial.

Comment: Perdonen, soy nuevo en esta pagina, lo que quiero hacer es cargar en la esp8266 un archivo en formato json a la esp(esto lo hago con ESPlorer, cargo el archivo en formato json a la esp y después el programa en lua), pero ahora quiero leer ese archivo y asignarle una ip estática con los datos que contiene el json.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la librería [cjson](http://www.kyne.com.au/~mark/software/lua-cjson-manual.html) de LUA, aunque buscando un poco hay otras alternativas como la de [Jeffery Friedl](http://regex.info/blog/lua/json). La ventaja del primero es la velocidad y la del segundo que es sólo un fichero de LUA.

Ejemplo cjson:

```
-- abre fichero json
file = io.open("fichero.json", "r")

-- indica que vamos a usar file como fichero por defecto 
io.input(file)

-- carga fichero
textojson = io.read("*all")    

-- decodifica  y lo usa
t = cjson.decode( textojson )
for k,v in pairs(t) do print(k,v) end

--cierra fichero
io.close()
```

De todas formas, si el fichero de configuración es tuyo, conoces el formato de las líneas y no varía en el tiempo, a lo mejor te puedes plantear realizar el parsing a mano:

```
file.open( "fichero.txt", "r") 
while true 
do 
    line = file.readline() 
    if (line == nil) then break 
    //ToDo: aquí el código
end 
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

La verdad veo mejor `dkjson`

Los instalas con luarocks con `sudo luarocks install dkjson` o bien en Debian/Ubuntu con `sudo apt-get install lua-dkjson`, tiene demasiadas utilidades para json

```
json = require 'dkjson'

archivo = io.read("tu.json", 'r')

texto = archivo:read("*all")

diccionario = json.decode(texto)

for i,v in pairs(diccionario) do
    print(i, v)
end
```